# Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /var/www/html/ech/user/actions/punish.php on line 24

Tags: php, sql

So I have a game server and I'm writing a php script called Echelon that allows me to interact with my gameservers database to view all information about the players etc, I'm trying to write a form to punish a player and post the punishment data to the database but im getting this error when posting the form
**Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /var/www/html/ech/user/actions/punish.php on line 24**

Here is my code, any help appreciated :)

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL); 
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
if (!empty($_POST["punishmenttype"])) {
$punishmenttype = $_POST['punishmenttype'];
$reason = $_POST['reason'];
$duration = $_POST['duration'];
$timescale = $_POST['timescale'];
$time = time();

if ($timescale == 'minutes') {
$duration = ($duration*60);
} elseif ($timescale == 'hours') {
$duration = ($duration*60*60);
} elseif ($timescale == 'days') {
$duration = ($duration*60*60*24);
} elseif ($timescale == 'weeks') {
$duration = ($duration*60*60*24*7); }
$timeexpire = ($time+$duration);

$sql = "INSERT INTO penalties (id, type, client_id, admin_id, duration, inactive, reason, data, time_add, time_edit, time_expire)
VALUES ('NULL', '$punishmenttype', '586', '$echelonid', '$duration', '0', '$reason', '', '$time', '$time', '$timeexpire')";
$result = mysql_query($query);
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $con->error;
}else{ }
?>
<div id="container" class="actionstabcontainer">
<h4 align=center>Punish User</h4>

<form  method="POST" align="center">
<select name="punishmenttype">
<option value="Notice">Notice</option>
<option value="Warning">Warning</option>
<option value="Tempban">Tempban</option>
</select>

<input type="text" name="duration" class="punishtextbox" style="width:55px" placeholder="Duration">

<select name="timescale">
<option value="minutes">Minutes</option>
<option value="hours">Hours</option>
<option value="days">Days</option>
<option value="weeks">Weeks</option>
</select>

<input type="text" name="reason" class="punishtextbox" style="width:140px" placeholder="Reason">
<input type="submit">
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: Where's the connection there? You didn't include in your connection.

Comment: line 24 in _that_ code is `}else{ }` ...

Comment: Where you declared the `$con`?

Comment: Once you've fixed that you might want to consider using [PDO](http://www.php.net/pdo) since mysql_* functions are deprecated as of version 5.4 - plus your syntax is vulnerable to SQL Injection that needs refactoring too.  Also Any version of php < 5.6 is also vulnerable given they are end of life.  From this I take it you're new, and should also consider a framework like [Laravel](http://laravel.com) or [Symfony](https://symfony.com/what-is-symfony)

Comment: The connection is defined in a different file which calls this file with an include

Comment: @Meathanjay - The }else{ } is from the "if (!empty($_POST["punishmenttype"])) {" statement

Comment: Check that `error` method is exists on that object, may be there no error and error method is not set?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your `$con` is not defined, unless it is somehow included elsewhere. Ensure that `$con` is defined and assigned to in a way that it is accessible to this page.

Also, you define your query in a `$sql` variable, yet cal `mysql_query($query)`. Where is `$query` defined?

Comment: It is defined elsewhere :)

Comment: Then it is not included in the same scope and prior to your use of it. Try redefining it just before you use it in this file and see if your error clears up.

Comment: $sql = "INSERT INTO penalties (id, type, client_id, admin_id, duration, inactive, reason, data, time_add, time_edit, time_expire)
VALUES ('NULL', '$punishmenttype', '586', '$echelonid', '$duration', '0', '$reason', '', '$time', '$time', '$timeexpire')";
$result = mysql_query($query);

where is $query ? you have used worng variable